# How can I create an if else statement with this situatiion?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I want a command that if I enter  nothing or null value it will not execute my insert command.Im using c# and sql server. My code is like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Records ([Student ID], [First Name], 
                    [Last Name], [Middle Initial], Gender, Address, Status, 
                    Year, Email, Course, [Contact Number])
                   VALUES    (  @StudentID,  @FirstName, @LastName ,
                         @MiddleInitial,  @Gender, @Address, @Status, @Year,  
                         @Email, @Course, @ContactNumber)";


        SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@StudentID", SqlDbType.NChar);
        p1.Value = textBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
        SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        p2.Value = textBox2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
        SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        p3.Value = textBox3.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p3);
        SqlParameter p4 = new SqlParameter("@MiddleInitial", SqlDbType.NChar);
        p4.Value = comboBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p4);
        SqlParameter p5 = new SqlParameter("@Gender", SqlDbType.NChar);
        p5.Value = comboBox2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p5);
        SqlParameter p6 = new SqlParameter("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        p6.Value = textBox4.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p6);
        SqlParameter p7 = new SqlParameter("@Status", SqlDbType.NChar);
        p7.Value = comboBox3.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p7);
        SqlParameter p8 = new SqlParameter("@Year", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        p8.Value = comboBox4.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p8);
        SqlParameter p9 = new SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        p9.Value = textBox5.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p9);
        SqlParameter p10 = new SqlParameter("@Course", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        p10.Value = comboBox5.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p10);
        SqlParameter p11 = new SqlParameter("@ContactNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        p11.Value = textBox6.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p11);

        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox3.Text = "";
        textBox4.Text = "";
        textBox5.Text = "";
        textBox6.Text = "";
        comboBox1.Text = "";
        comboBox2.Text = "";
        comboBox3.Text = "";
        comboBox4.Text = "";
        comboBox5.Text = "";
        MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted!", "Information ... ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1); 
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

Comment: Nothing or null value for which parameter?

Comment: I want it in student id, first name and last name.

Comment: In my modest opinion some [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) is needed in your code

Comment: A truly terrifying bit of code. You empty your text boxes before you execute the command! What if something goes wrong? The data has gone.
May I humbly suggest you pass your data to a stored procedure with a return value - incorporate some error checking in the stored procedure - return a value that allows your front end to understand what has happened and handle it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you generate constraint in the table, when you can try insert null values, and in your program can you get the exception.

other alternative is make a loop and check all values in paramaters on cmd.Parameters, and if you found one null, nothing or blank  you should not send the insert to database.

Answer (score 0):

you can check as below

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox3.Text))
{
  // your code

}
```

if you want to avoid string only having spaces like `"             "` you can use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` method (available on .NET 4.0 +)

Comment: note: IsNullOrWhiteSpace is available only in Microsoft .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Parameters is a collection. To check if some of its value is null:

```
if (cmd.Parameters.Contains(System.DBNull.Value))
{
   // A parameter has a null value
}
```

Comment: it has an error. The error said "The SQlParameter Collection only accepts non-null SQLparamter type objects, not DBNull objects

Answer (score 0):

As Damith suggested you can use string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace or write a separate validate function that validates the data in the text boxes.

```
    bool Validate()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox2.Text)) // For textboxes that need validation
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Instead of using these if else statements have a look at [Contracts.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808.aspx)